# How is it possible to add an imageView to the launchscreen.storyboard programatically?

Tags: ios, swift, uiimageview, launch-screen

I know that classes cannot be created in the `launchscreen.storyboard`, but how is it possible to programatically add an `imageView` in my launchscreen in swift. Thanks in advance.